# What does exactly the nextNot function do in SonarQube's library?

Tags: python, sonarqube

You can see here the definition of the function:

```java
* Creates parsing expression - "next not".
* During execution of this expression parser will execute sub-expression once.
* This expression succeeds only if sub-expression fails.
*
* @param e  sub-expression
* @throws IllegalArgumentException if given argument is not a parsing expression
*/
public final Object nextNot(Object e) {
return new NextNotExpression(convertToExpression(e));
}
```

If I understand correctly, if the object `e` is seen, it will fail.

However, I'm looking at SonarQube's grammar for Python and `PRINT_EXP` is like this:

```
b.rule(PRINT_STMT).is("print", b.nextNot("("), b.firstOf( 
  b.sequence(">>", TEST, b.optional(b.oneOrMore(",", TEST), b.optional(","))), 
  b.optional(TEST, b.zeroOrMore(",", TEST), b.optional(","))));
```

Does this mean that if a parenthesis is seen, it will be considered as a failure?
Because in Python 3.x, print is a function.

Comment: you may wish to correct the spelling in the title.

Comment: Thanks to jonrsharpe for making it more clear and concise !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nextNot` is a kind of negative matching. In the example you highlight, `PRINT_STMT` does not match when `print` is followed by `(`.

Calls to the `print` function in Python 3 should match `EXPRESSION_STMT`.

Note: `nextNot` is part of the [SSLR library](https://github.com/SonarSource/sslr) which is independent from SonarQube.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer ! So if I understand well, they kept that to be compatible with both Python 2 and 3 ?

Comment: Yes, that's a way to have the grammar compatible with both Python 2 and 3.